# what is PyTables external sorting algorithm?

Tags: python, sorting, pytables

I need to know which sorting algorithm PyTables is using to create completely sorted indices. The code in [Github](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/blob/develop/tables/index.py#L65) has reference to both *mergesort* and *quicksort* but I'm still clueless on how they're actually being used. Any thoughts?

Comment: Based on the comments in the code you linked to, it seems the algorithm was changed from quicksort to mergesort. It's not clear what #441 is referring to. Generally, external (disk based) sorts use some type of merge sort.

Comment: Yhea those are my thoughts as well, but since I'm using PyTables as part of an academic work, it's important I get the details right as well. I'll try to contact the devs.